# find a value of table cell

Tags: javascript, cell, innerhtml

```
<tbody id="contacttable">
</tbody>
<script> 
  var hrtypeCode = document.getElementById('hrtypeCode').value;
  var hrCode = document.getElementById('hrCode').value;
  var hrName = document.getElementById('hrName').value;
  var hrDesc = document.getElementById('hrDesc').value;
  for(i=0;i<hrCode.length; i++){        
    if(hrCode[i]!="") {
      var table = document.getElementById("contacttable");
      var slNo = table.rows.length;
      var tr = table.insertRow(slNo-1);
      tr.id = 'list_tr_' + slNo;
      tr.innerHTML ='<td><input type="text" name="hrtypeCode" value="'+hrtypeCode[i]+'" ></td><td><input type="text" name="hrCode" value="'+hrCode[i]+ '"></td><td><input type="text" name="hrName" value="'+hrName[i]+'" ></td>';
      count++;
    }
  }
</script> 
<i>
```

how to find out the cell values.i have tried the following code but it showing entire TD row

```
tbl.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
  alert(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
```

Kindly help in finding the value..    thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table cells don't have values, only input elements do. You need to access the `<input>` element within the table cell.

Use:

```
tbl.rows[i].cells[j].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Rtydd/1/)